# Explanation of Code: Dealing with min and max - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {

return Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1)) +myMin;

}
```

I need a refresher on what the return statement is doing. I understand it creates a range for instance, 5 - 15. But I don't get why I'm subtracting the max from the min and adding + 1 and then +myMin.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. See what happens if you don't subtract max from the min, or whatever. This is exactly how I learned how to program; watching the code do its thing, then altering the code to see how that changed things.

Comment: It's basic math. Run through a few cases on a piece of paper. I assume you know that `Math.random` returns a number in the range of `[0, 1)`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Good find! I forgot this explanation existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't get why im subtracting the max from the min and adding + 1 and then +myMin.

First remember that `Math.random()` returns a value in the range of `[0, 1)`.

Lets start from the end:

- `+ myMin` is done to ensure that the result is larger or equal to `myMin`.
  Lets assume `Math.random()` returns `0`. Then `Math.floor(...)` returns `0`. If we didn't `+ myMin`, return result would be `0` instead of `myMin`.
- `+ 1` is done to get random values that **include** `myMax`. Remember that `Math.random()` never returns `1`, only values close to `1`. I.e. the `Math.floor(Math.random() * myMax)` can never be `myMax` unless we add `1`.
- `myMax - myMin` is done because we do `+ myMin` above. We have to account for increasing the result by `myMin`.

  Lets assume `Math.random()` returns `0.5` and our range is `100 - 120`. Without `- myMin`, we would get

  ```
   Math.floor(0.5 * 120) + 100 = 60 + 100 = 160
  ```

  That's clearly larger than `120`. If we include `- myMin`:

  ```
   Math.floor(0.5 * (120 - 100)) + 100 = (0.5 * 20) + 100 = 110
  ```

  we get `110` which is exactly in the middle of our range (which makes sense intuitively since we get `0.5` as a random value).

Answer (score 1):

Math.random returns float number between 0 to 1. For example if you take 1 to 10 range. Then Math.random will return minimum 0 and maximum 1 then you multiply it with 10-1=9. And you get 0 to 9. But when you add the minimum it will be increased to 1 to 10.

Comment: Actually, it returns a number (JS has no concept of "float") between zero and one, but not including one.

Answer (score 1):

Correction - it's not creating a range, it is generating a random Integer number between a given range of numbers ( minimum and maximum number).

E.g. (5, 15) = (min, max)

Will result in a number that is in between this range.

Code explanation :

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1)) +myMin;
```

Let's assume both max and min are = 15

So the above will look like:

Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 15 + 1)) + 15;

Which is equal to = 15, since  0 <= Math.random() * (1) < 1 so the floor of this is 0.

If you don't add that 1, it will not be valid for this corner case.

You add minimum to make sure the value remains between min and max.