# Can anyone explain the below code logic in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In some coding practice websites, I found below assignment operation for  generating a random whole number that falls within a range of two specific numbers.

To do this, we'll define a minimum number min and a maximum number max.

Here's the formula we'll use. Take a moment to read it and try to understand what this code is doing:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

This formula is bit ambiguous to me.
Could anyone please explain the logic.

Comment: Looks like a way to generate a random whole number between (inclusive) min and max.

Comment: `Math.random()` generates a pseudo-random number in the interval [0, 1). To get a number >= 1 you have to scale the result.

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Have you read [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)?

Comment: If you don't know what it does, why not simply not use it? Otherwise, why not run the code and debug it?

Comment: Take the formula apart and evaluate each part in the console, like `a = max - min + 1; b = Math.random() * a` etc

Comment: It is explained in detail here: [Explanation of Code: Dealing with min and max - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753919)

Comment: @jabaa every language/technology/tool has its own documentation end to end and books/articles related to it. So what is the purpose of stackoverflow then? Please let others reply atleast. I saw most of your comments are like this only on other posts also.Even there are other community members trying to help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for beginners tutorials. There are hundreds online. It's for specific programming questions and _"asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) That's how this platform works and why multiple users downvoted your question. You should probably know that multiple downvoted questions will block your account from asking new questions.

Comment: You should read [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this:

1. First lets look at `Math.random()`. According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

> The `Math.random()` function returns a pseudo-random number in the form of a floating point number in the range from 0 - 1 (including 0, but not 1)

2. Multiply it by `(max - min + 1)` will give you `offset` in the range between `min` and `max` and will make sure you won't exceed this limit.
3. Adding `+ min` will make sure you get the shifting from [0 to `offset`] to [min to `offset + min`] which we said is limited by `max`.
4. Finally `Math.floor` to make it integer number instead of float (its floor and not `Math.ceil` because the original `Math.random()` is not including the `1`).